# Discrete math: probability of picking certain hands with a preset condition

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

In 5-card draw poker, a player receives an initial hand of 5 cards, and is then allowed to replace up to three of her cards with the remaining cards in the deck.

(b) Suppose that, among the initial 5 cards, there is exactly one pair (e.g., 8 \heartsuit, 8 \clubsuit) and one “kicker” (e.g., A \spadesuit). The player decides to keep the pair and the kicker, and replaces the other two cards.
What is the probability of her ending up with:

3 of a kind? (note: this means exactly 3-of-a-kind, not including those that can also fall in a higher category. The same goes for the following two questions)

2 pair?

full house?

Answer (score 1):

So we have a pair and a kicker. We then choose two cards from $49$. We want either two more kickers or another of the same rank as the pair. These outcomes are disjoint, so we add them together.

So to get three of a kind, we have $\binom{2}{1} * \binom{47}{1}$ ways to pick the third card and another card of different rank. Now if we allow for four of a kind, we would simply consider $1$ way for that to happen. So we would have a probability as shown below. If you don't want to allow for four of a kind, just remove the $1$ term below.

$$\dfrac{ \binom{2}{1} * \binom{47}{1} + 1}{\binom{49}{2}} = \dfrac{47*2 + 1}{49 * 24}$$

For (c), if we have a two-pair, we must draw another kicker or we must draw another pair, and so there are $\binom{3}{1} * \binom{46}{1}$ ways to draw the second kicker without allowing for three of a kind. To get another pair, we have $\binom{44}{1} * \binom{3}{1}$ ways to do this. If you do allow for three of a kind, you add to that $\binom{5}{2}$, as you have two $8$'s and three aces from which to choose. Again, divide out by $\binom{49}{2}$.

Note: I am assuming the replacement happens first, then you get the re-draw. If the replaced cards go back into the deck after you get the new cards, then the probabilities will be different. I'm not a poker player, so I apologize for faulty assumptions.

Comment: We figured out 3 of a kind and full house but your 2 pair is off. What we've done is there's 2 cases, one where you get another Ace or the other where you get a pair of two other cards.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I've updated my answer!

Comment: we just figured it out. it's (3(9*4+2*3)+9C(4,2)+2C(3,2))/C(47,2)

Answer (score 0):

There are $49 \choose 2$ ways to choose the two new cards that the player gets dealt. In order to make 3 of a kind and no higher hand, one card chosen has to be an 8 (two choices) and the other card has to be neither an ace nor an 8. So after the 8 is chosen, there are $44$ ways to choose the remaining card so that the hand is exactly 3 of a kind. The ordering of the cards doesn't matter so you get $((2*44)/2!)/{49 \choose 2}$ as the probability.

Similarly reason for the other cases. In order to get two pair, either the one of the two new cards is an ace and the other card is neither an ace nor an eight, or the two cards must be a pair different from aces or eights. And to get a full house, the player must get exactly one eight and one ace.